# Print perl string with question mark

Tags: perl

I have this two line of code:

```
print $line . "\n";
print $line . "?feed=rss\n";
```

Can someone explain me why the output is:

```
htttp://string1string2
?feed=rsstring1string2
```

And is not:

```
htttp://string1string2
htttp://string1string2?feed=rss
```

Answer (score 6):

Because

```
$line = "htttp://string1string2\r";
```

and your terminal responds to a carriage return by moving the cursor to the first column of the current row.

Comment: ITYM left column. Which is the expected result of CR.

Comment: I used chomp(), but is fixed now by adding first: $/ = "\r\n"

Comment: @Barmar, Fixed. (The term I used was very very wrong. "Home row" is the ASDF row of a keyboard!)

Comment: `chomp($line);` will not remove carriage return (unless you inadvisably changed `$/`), so it won't help. you could use `$line =~ s/\r?\n\z/;` or even `$line =~ s/\s+\z//;`.

Comment: Or `binmode $filehandle, ':crlf';` to deal with the problem at the source.